# color value drawable resource issue

Tags: java, android, resources, drawable

I have an image that is 1900*1200 in a folder called drawable-sw600dp that id like to have used on a nexus 7. When I try to run the app the main activity the screen is white and I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Color value '@drawable-sw600dp/background5' must start with #
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getColor(ResourceHelper.java:71)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:248)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:782)
```

Could it be that the image is too large to use? Or what could cause this error to happen?

This is in my activity_main.xml where the background is set:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background5"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

In my other folders drawable-hdpi,-mdpi there is no problem. However I made the .jpg image a higher resolution and now it creates this error, thats why I suspect the high resolution is causing the issue.

Comment: android is complaining that your color does not start with #. Post background5.xml

Comment: background5 is a .jpg image

Comment: Show us where you call background5 in your code

Comment: My response has been updated. jpg is not supported.

Comment: @ez4nick, try cleaning your project?  For some reason it thinks you are referring to a color value.  Are you possibly using the same filename for an XML drawable?

Answer (score 54):

Remove the '-' in the file name.

NOTE: '-' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore

Comment: Is there some documentation to support this madness? I just pulled out all of my hair before stumbling across this answer. Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem but in my case the file name started with numbers. I changed the file name to start with letters and it was working.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3abackground) jpg is not supported. Use png instead:

> A drawable to use as the background. This can be either a reference to a full drawable resource (such as a PNG image, 9-patch, XML state list description, etc), or a solid color such as "#ff000000" (black).

Comment: I understand the doc says that jpg is not supported, however I have other layouts using a .jpg image perfectly fine as the background and also when I use a lower resolution .jpg image 1280*720 it works fine. Is it possible the resolution could cause the error?

Comment: Maybe, when you use something not described as the documentation, it might sometimes work and sometimes not work, without knowing why. Just follow the guideline.

Comment: It did end up being the resolution of the image, I tried slightly lower resolutions and those worked fine.

Comment: WRONG!  I just changed one of my png images to a jpg, and ran my app without problems. On this page it says A "bitmap graphic file (.png, .jpg, or .gif)." http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

Some people have mentioned restarting Eclipse has worked, but that didn’t work for me.

Instead, I found that I had to simply rename the image file so that it did NOT start with a number. All icons in the Android Developer Icon Pack start with a number, and I had just copied the one over. It appears that if the file starts with a number, it is assumed to be the start of a hexadecimal color value, and hence looks for the # symbol.

working with: Eclipse Juno 3.7.2, Android SDK 21.1