# How to fix android error 'Color value must start with #'?

Tags: android

I was trying to use an icon from [this page](https://design.google.com/icons/index.html) in my layout as follows

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_backspace_black_24dp"
/>
```

but it could not be rendered because of an error

```
Color value '@drawable/ic_backspace_black_24dp' must start with #
```

I found two related issues in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599262/color-value-drawable-resource-issue) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971573/setting-drawable-as-text-color-raise-an-exception-color-value-must-start-with) which did not help resolve the issue.

There is no dash ('-') in the filename, the file-format is a 'png' and there is no `res/color` directory in my project.

All my colors defined in `colors.xml` start with a `#`.

So how to fix this error?

Comment: What is the content of your drawable file?

Answer (score 4):

Simply rename your file name by removing the numbers and only keep lower case letters or underscores.

Comment: I had to remove everything but letters and it worked. Magic.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved: I forgot to remember that the android sources on the internet are really outdated, and almost none of the documentation works as-is!

The folder `res/drawable` as suggested in the [android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html) is deprecated! The folder is now named `mipmap`! So the simple solution is to have the following layout to fix the problem:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_backspace_black_24dp"
/>
```

Never trust the android developer documentation ... !

Comment: You can still use `drawable/` for shapes, layers etc

Comment: I had this problem but it apparently had to do with the image file name. After I renamed it to "ic_file_name" the error went away.

Comment: Solved my problem! Changed drawable to mipmap!

Comment: `res/drawable` is certainly not deprecated. Mipmap has a particular use that is not necessarily suitable for any and all drawables.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the '_" underscores and make the name shorter.  Not sure why but that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file drawable/ic_backspace_black_24dp.

If you downloaded the SVG version you will able to open as a text file. Check if the android:fillColor has the #.

Anyway if you are using Android Studio those icons can be downloaded very easily using Vector Asset Studio:

- Right click in drawable
- new
- vector assets
- choose the icon you want

You have more info of this feature [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html).